# Getting Images from node JS ( or database ) to React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, knex.js

I managed to upload a file in React JS and store it in my NodeJS public folder, i am also storing them in a database(just the file names) 
What I'm trying to do is now that my files are uploaded, how can i GET the files from the server ( or database or both ). 
My upload function in the front-end looks like this:

```
    onSubmit = (event) => {
      //some security here so i make sure that the upload is an valid image 
      //I am uploading Ads for my page
      const data=new FormData();
      data.append('adimage',adimage);
      data.append('adurl',adurl);

      fetch('http://localhost:3001/uploadad',{
          method:'POST',
          body:data,
      }).then((response)=>{
          response.json().then(ad=>{
              let ads=this.state.ads;
              ads=[...ads,ad.file];
              this.setState({ads:ads});
          }) 
              .catch(err=>console.log('failed to upload image'));
      }).catch(err=>console.log('error uploading image'));
```

And the NodeJS back-end:

```
const uploadAd= (req,res,db,urlExists)=>{
//some security here so i make sure that the upload is an valid image
db('ads')
    .insert({
        image: ad.name,
        url: adurl
    })
    .returning('id')
    .then(id => {
        db('ads').update({
            image: `ad${id[0]}.${ext}`
        })
         //just want to store all ad images as ad{adid}
            .where('id', '=', id[0])
            .returning(['image', 'url'])
            .then(data => {
                let img = data[0].image;
                let url = data[0].url;

                const reqPath = path.join(__dirname, '..\\..\\');
                //uploading the file to the public folder
                ad.mv(`${reqPath}/public/${img}`, (err) =>{
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).send(err);
                    }
                    res.json({
                        file: `${img}`,
                        url: url
                    });
                });
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Now that my files are stored in a folder in the server side how can i fetch the data in the client side?
 Can i just store them in my database without the need to upload the files, but from what i know that is not a good practice ? 
I am pretty new to react and node and this is my first post here. Thank you

Comment: You can add a route to your node backend that will serve an image; like this: `http://localhost:3001/img/123` where node will read the id 123 and send back the image file. Are you using just node or express, too?

Comment: you have this `${reqPath}/public/${img}` to create an url to your images

Comment: Yes I am using express aswell. In React i want to get all images that have been uploaded, because i don't fully understand how this works, my more precise question is can i get those images from  the folder where they are uploaded in node?

Comment: So i have all the ads as a state in my **Ads Component** , now i just need to pass them as props to  **AdImage Component** which contains the image, and there fetch the specific image using  `${reqPath}/public/${img}` ? I thought that i could fetch all images at once. If so thanks a lot this question is solved :)

Comment: Off the scope of your question, but you should probably add a service like s3, or the equivalent in your setup. Otherwise this files will mess your repo, or fill out your server, and clog your server and slow down other responses.